# When to use enumerate function specifically and can same task can be done with for look and Zip function

Tags: python-3.x

Im not sure when to use enumerate function and can this task be done with other for loop methods with zip function in it

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: `enumerate(lst)` is equivalent to `zip(range(len(lst)), lst)` but with much better readability.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
enumerate(iterable, start=0)
```

The enumerate function yields an enumerate object which is simply an object containing tuples. The tuple contains two values first in the index of the element and second the value. The start is by default assigned a value of 0. The following example shows how to use enumerate to traverse a list.

```
l = ['Apple', 'Banana', 'guava', 'Strawberry', 'Pineapple']
enumerateObject = enumerate(l)

print(list(enumerateObject)) # an enumerate object

# using enumerateObject to loop
for ind, fruit in enumerateObject:
    print(ind, fruit)
```

Zip function is used to traverse two or more iterables(list, tuples, dictionaries etc) together. Zip like an enumerate function generates a zip object which contains tuples of corresponding elements. Zip is used on multiple iterables while enumerate is used on one.

```
f = ['Apple', 'Banana', 'guava', 'Strawberry', 'Pineapple']
c = ['Red', 'yellow', 'green', 'pinkish red', 'Brown']

print(list(zip(f,c)))
for ele1, ele2 in zip(f, c):
    print(ele1, 'is', ele2, 'in colour')
```

To understand them better try to change the program yourself. Please mark the answer correct.

Happy coding!